# webcam recording with python tkinter

Tags: python

I want to record video (not audio) from webcam.
I have put  two buttons for start recording & stop recording.
As program starts it pick image from camera & shows on screen.works perfect.
My problem is when i click start recording & after some times stop recording,
only avi file created ,with 0K or 6K size found. No further recording found.

```js
import tkinter
import cv2
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk


stopb = None

class App():
    def __init__(self, window, window_title):
        self.window = window
        self.window.title = window_title
        self.ok = False
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.width = self.video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        self.height = self.video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
        #create videowriter
        self.fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
        self.out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',self.fourcc,10,(640,480))
        # Create a canvas that can fit the above video source size
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, width=self.width, height=self.height)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.opencamera = tkinter.Button(window, text="open camera", command=self.open_camera)
        self.opencamera.pack()
        self.closecamera = tkinter.Button(window, text="close camera", command=self.close_camera)
        self.closecamera.pack()
        self.delay = 10
        self.update()

        # After it is called once, the update method will be automatically called every delay milliseconds
        self.window.mainloop()

    def update(self):
        ret, frame = self.video.read()
        if self.ok == 'T':
            self.out.write(frame)
        if ret:
            self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=PIL.Image.fromarray(frame))
            self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo, anchor=tkinter.NW)

        self.window.after(self.delay, self.update)

    def open_camera(self):
        self.ok = True
        print("camera opened")
        print(self.ok)


    def close_camera(self):
        print("camera closed")
        self.ok = False
        self.video.release()
        self.out.release()

    def __del__(self):
        if self.video.isOpened():
            self.video.release()
            self.out.release()


App(tkinter.Tk(), "mywindow")
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `if self.ok == 'T':
            self.out.write(frame)`?
Shouldn't you just write `if self.ok`?

Comment: If self.ok == 'T' then start recording, i am new for python there may be other ways to write same thing.

Comment: The problem is that you're comparing `self.ok`, which you are always using as a boolean value, with a characther (or string) `'T'`, so that will ALWAYS be `False`, and you will never write your frame into your output. `True != 'T'` `False != 'T'`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're never writing anything to your output, as `if self.ok == 'T'` will never evaluate to true. You should change it to just `if self.ok`, the same thing you did with `ret`.

```
def update(self):
        ret, frame = self.video.read()
        if self.ok:
            self.out.write(frame)
        if ret:
            self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=PIL.Image.fromarray(frame))
            self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo, anchor=tkinter.NW)

        self.window.after(self.delay, self.update)
```

Comment: yes, you are right, self.ok that is my mistake. but for ret will true if image captured ok from webcam. image from webcam is display works perfect. Now i am going to change self.ok as boolean & update you. Thanks for pointing my mistake.

Comment: now recording started, but when i record for 1 minute, recorded video play time is near 35 second. Can some one point out mistake.

Comment: @RoshanHemrajani I can't reproduce this behavior. The recording says 35 seconds even after closing the app? Have you changed anything in your code?

Answer (score 0):

One more issue I found was- after clicking the close camera button followed by the open camera button, the new recording won't start.
Meaning you will just be able to record the first video captured before clicking the close camera button.

This is because the close camera function releases the video object and output object thus video.read() of the update function won't work.

A quick fix is to create a method of set_camera() which creates the video object. Call this function every time in open camera.

https://replit.com/@AmitYadav4/video-record-in-tkinker-canvas